# interchanging the proton and electron in a neutral atom

Tags: atomic-physics

what we have to see if we replace the electron from proton and proton in nucleus is replaced by electron ? Will it change the atomic structure of every substance or it changes only in calculating reydberg constant?

Comment: You can always attempt to solve Schrodinger's equation from the perspective of the proton 'orbiting' the electron. The Born-Oppenheimer approximation is just that - an approximation. A full solution to the hydrogen atom incorporates the movement of both the proton and the electron. That is just a much harder problem to solve than the standard one in introductory quantum mechanics.

Comment: +1 for the extraordinary question. The usual answer will be that nature is not built that way. But maybe someone has the time to spin the question further and something interesting comes out of it.